# Which is the best reporting tool in angular js along with nodejs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I am currently building a single page application using angularjs along with nodejs. I want to generate some detailed reports which is not possible through  charts. Could anyone suggest me the best reporting tools in client side.

Comment: How is it not doable with charts? Won't reports just use the same structured data as well... charts? I don't think there is a specific AngularJS report "tool" as such

Comment: @ Rohan Büchner, for example i need a report like detailed attendance report. We can't visualize whole data in the case of charts but it could be possible through table view like crystal  report in Dot net framework.

Comment: Then make use of the html table element if you need a table? Use a combination of  charts and default html elements to build up the report/view

Comment: I guess if you must generate it server side. There are a few options... But then you're not using angular per se

Comment: You could build a SSRS report and have the user download it, (if you're using .Net somewhere in the stack)... I also just came across this PDF generation framework for node which could probably be used. http://www.feedhenry.com/server-side-pdf-generation-node-js/

Comment: @ Rohan Büchner, Thank you for your valid suggestion.

Answer (score 5):

In terms of node and AngularJS & Node... you have a only few options available to you.

- The most likely one being a "Hybrid" report using Native HTML & a charting framework like D3 for example.

  - I've had lots of luck with [this directive](https://cmaurer.github.io/angularjs-nvd3-directives/) set for Angular & D3 in the past
- I just found this: [jsreport.net](http://jsreport.net/learn/pdf-reports-in-nodejs).

  - It looks like the only NodeJs reporting solution at the moment other than the above route..
- If you have access to other tech stacks, you could generate the report server side and offer the users a download link. (But then its not strictly Angular/Node)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. Let me try this :)

Comment: See also http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/26543/reporting-and-report-generation-for-a-web-application-nodejs-angularjs